# kotlin datatable structure to hold and sort data

Tags: kotlin, datatable

So i have this strucuture that i use to hold data in that will feed a kotlin/js table

```
data class TableData<T : Any>(
    var items: List<T>,
    var fieldList: MutableList<KProperty1<T, Comparable<*>>> = mutableListOf(),
) : Iterable<T> {
    override fun iterator() = items.iterator()

    fun handleSortRequest(incoming: KProperty1<T, Comparable<*>>) {
        fieldList.add(incoming)
        fieldList.reverse()
        items = items.sortedWith(compareBy(*fieldList.toTypedArray()))
    }
}
```

and it  works great, i am able to sort each column via something like

```
 sort(Meal::calories)
```

I would like to expand upon it by adding arrows to the columns for ascending and descending like many of the popular data tables, is this possible?  How would i do it.

my test class is

```
data class Meal(
    val calories: Int,
    val salad: String,
    val mainCourse: String,
    val desert: String,
)
```

and i feed the table with this list of meals.

```
val mealList = listOf(
    Meal(calories = 90, salad = "Fruit Salad", mainCourse = "Pork", desert = "cookies"),
    Meal(calories = 10, salad = "Shrimp Salad", mainCourse = "Burgers", desert = "cookies"),
    Meal(calories = 30, salad = "Tuna Salad", mainCourse = "Chicken", desert = "pie"),
    Meal(calories = 40, salad = "Cobb Salad", mainCourse = "Steak", desert = "jello"),
    Meal(calories = 40, salad = "Caesar Salad", mainCourse = "Salmon", desert = "pudding"),
    Meal(calories = 40, salad = "Potato Salad", mainCourse = "Hot Dogs", desert = "cake"),
    Meal(calories = 20, salad = "Garden Salad", mainCourse = "Eggs", desert = "ice cream"),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you need to pass another parameter to your `handleSortRequest` method, specifying the sort direction. Also, you need to change the type of items stored in `fieldList` to store selectors alongside with sort direction.

Now, a comparator could be built from this data:

```
data class TableData<T : Any>(
    var items: List<T>,
    var fieldList: MutableList<Pair<KProperty1<T, Comparable<*>>, Boolean>> = mutableListOf(),
) : Iterable<T> {
    override fun iterator() = items.iterator()

    fun handleSortRequest(incoming: KProperty1<T, Comparable<*>>, isAscending: Boolean = true) {
        fieldList.add(incoming to isAscending)
        fieldList.reverse()
        
        val comparator = fieldList
            .map { (selector, isAsc) -> if (isAsc) compareBy(selector) else compareByDescending(selector) }
            .reduce { acc, x -> acc.thenComparing(x) }

        items = items.sortedWith(comparator)
    }
}
```